# How to map a list of (x,y) pairs to function f(x,y) in Pool.map?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, parallel-processing, arguments

Suppose I have a want to plot the density on the x-y plane, the density is defined as:

```
def density(x,y):
    return x**2 +y**2
```

If I have many points `(x1,y1), (x2,y2)...` to calculate, therefore I want to do it parallel. I found the doc [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html) and try to do the following:

```
pointsList = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]
from multiprocessing import Pool
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as p:
        print(p.map(density,pointsList ))
```

the error occurs and it seems that I failed to pass the args to the function, how to do this?

---

### Edit:

the error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-647-1e2a1f0007fb> in <module>()
      5 from multiprocessing import Pool
      6 if __name__ == '__main__':
----> 7     with Pool() as p:
      8         print(p.map(density,pointsList ))

AttributeError: __exit__
```

---

### Edit2:

If I can't do this simple parallel in `python2.7`, how can I do it in `python3.5` for instance?

Comment: "the error occurs". It's not very helpful to say that there was an error, and not say what the error was.

Comment: I never said you can't do it in python 2.7 ... I only said you can't use the `with` syntax.  You're using the wrong doc, this is for python 2 : https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: @abccd No matter 2.7 or 3.3, I just want it works, can you give a worked example in your answer, despite the version.

Comment: There, I added a working example for python 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `Pool` in a context manager was added in Python 3.3. Since you tagged Python 2.7, you can't use the `with` syntax.

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool):

> New in version 3.3: Pool objects now support the context management
>   protocol – see Context Manager Types. `__enter__()` returns the pool
>   object, and `__exit__()` calls `terminate()`.

Here's the working example you wanted, for python 3.3+ :

```
def density(args):
    x, y = args
    return x**2 +y**2

pointsList = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]
from multiprocessing import Pool
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as p:
        print(p.map(density,pointsList ))
```

And since you're also using Python 2.7, you just need to not use the context manager and call `p.terminate()` instead:

```
def density(args):
    x, y = args
    return x**2 +y**2

pointsList = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]
from multiprocessing import Pool
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool()
    print(p.map(density,pointsList ))
    p.terminate()
```

Comment: So how can I use it for 3.5 for instance?

Comment: You can do what you're doing in your post as long as your python version is >= 3.3

Comment: It gives me an error: `TypeError: density() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`

Answer (score 0):

Need to change the density function to unpack the tuple argument

```
def density(z):
    (x,y) = z
    return x**2 +y**2
```

try not use the `with` and close the pool yourself after you are done with it. 
This way should be compatible for both python 2 and 3

```
from multiprocessing import Pool  
pointsList = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]
p = Pool()
print(p.map( density,pointsList ))
p.close()
```

or using `contextlib` module

```
from multiprocessing import Pool 
import contextlib
pointsList = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]
with contextlib.closing(Pool()) as p:
    print(p.map( density,pointsList ))
```

Comment: Have you tried this? It gives me an error `TypeError: density() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'` in `3`

Comment: sorry, didn't notice that, try out edited one and it works for me